# Updating database returns primary key error ASP.NET mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, duplicates, primary-key

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6z8-_TbInQ&list=PLRmyy9vm8xSLp6_s1ok74oFVpM5aRiORM&index=1) tutorial to create my own custom "blog" functionality, but instead of creating blog posts, it creates "projects" with a Title, Date Created, Short Description, Long Description, and Team Leader.

The following code is supposed to change a project's information if the int passed in the url matches its primary key, and if not, create a new project with all of the above parameters.

However, when it gets to model.SaveChanges (seen below), it throws an error.
I am aware that I'm working in MVC 5 and the tutorial is in MVC 3, but so far everything has translated relatively well.

**Here is my Controller**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SouthMeckNTHS.Models;
using SouthMeckNTHS.Extensions;
using System.Text;

namespace SouthMeckNTHS.Controllers
{
    public class ProjectsController : Controller
    {
        private ProjectsModel model = new ProjectsModel();

        // GET: Projects
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("My");
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult My()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Update(int? id, string title, string shortDescription, string longDescription, DateTime dateTime, string technologies)
        {
            //REMEMBER TO ADD PROJECT LEADER FUNCTIONALITY!!
            if (!User.IsInRole("ChapterAdvisor"))
            {
                RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            Project project = GetProject(id);
            project.Title = title;
            project.ShortDescription = shortDescription;
            project.LongDescription = longDescription;
            project.TimeCreated = dateTime;
            project.ProjectLeader = User.Identity.GetFirstName() + " " + User.Identity.GetLastName();
            project.Technologies.Clear();

            technologies = technologies ?? string.Empty;
            string[] technologyNames = technologies.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string technologyName in technologyNames)
            {
                project.Technologies.Add(GetTechnology(technologyName));
            }

            if (!id.HasValue)
            {
                model.Projects.Add(project);
            }
            try
            {
                model.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                Exception raise = dbEx;
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                            validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                            validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        // raise a new exception nesting
                        // the current instance as InnerException
                        raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                    }
                }
                throw raise;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = project.Id });
        }

        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            Project project = GetProject(id);
            StringBuilder technologyList = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (Technology technology in project.Technologies)
            {
                technologyList.AppendFormat("{0} ", technology.Name);
            }
            ViewBag.Technologies = technologyList.ToString();
            return View(project);
        }

        private Technology GetTechnology(string technologyName)
        {
            return model.Technologies.Where(x => x.Name == technologyName).FirstOrDefault() ?? new Technology() { Name = technologyName };
        }

        private Project GetProject(int? id)
        {
            return id.HasValue ? model.Projects.Where(x => x.Id == id).First() : new Project() { Id = 0 };
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Join()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the View**:

```
@model SouthMeckNTHS.Models.Project
@using SouthMeckNTHS.Extensions;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br /><br />

<form action="@Href("~/Projects/Update")" method="post" id="postForm">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @if (Model.Id != 0)
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.Id" />

    }

    @{ DateTime dateTime = Model.TimeCreated.Year > 2000 ? Model.TimeCreated : DateTime.Now; }
    <input type="text" name="dateTime" value="@dateTime" /> Date<br />
    <input type="text" name="title" value="@Model.Title" /> Project Name<br />
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Technologies, new SelectList(new List<Object> { new { value = "Animation", text = "Animation" }, new { value = "Robotics", text = "Robotics" }, new { value = "Architecture", text = "Architecture" }, new { value = "CAD", text = "CAD" }, new { value = "Websites", text = "Websites" }, new { value = "Games", text = "Games" }, new { value = "Biotechnology", text = "Biotechnology" }, new { value = "Club", text = "Club" }, new { value = "Other", text = "Other" } }, "value", "text"), new { @style = "border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;padding: 0.5em 1.07em 0.5em;background: #f5f5f5;font-size: 0.875rem;border-radius: 5px;width: 100%;line-height: 1.43;min-height: 3.5em;" })
    <textarea name="shortDescription" rows="5" cols="80">@Model.ShortDescription</textarea><br />
    <textarea name="longDescription" rows="10" cols="80">@Model.LongDescription</textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Changes" />
</form>
```

**And THIS is the error I get:
[Click Here to View the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGzw6.png)

**^The Image above is of the error reading**:

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Projects__3214EC0766FE6300'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Projects'. The duplicate key value is (0).
The statement has been terminated.

**And the subsequent text after it.**

Any ideas what is happening/how to fix it and why it is not working for me?
I don't understand why the tutorial's example doesn't throw the error about "duplicate keys" when mine is almost identitical.

Comment: Is the Id field defined as identity/auto-increment in the database?

Comment: No it was not. I just changed it.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Projects] (
    [Id]               INT             NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Title]            NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [TimeCreated]      DATETIME        NOT NULL,
    [ShortDescription] NVARCHAR (1000) NOT NULL,
    [LongDescription]  NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [ProjectLeader]    NVARCHAR (1000) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

Comment: Changing it did nothing, the error is still thrown.

Comment: Did you refresh the entity data model after making the db change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ef is trying to attach the entity (adding it) instead of modifying it, that's I guess because your context is tracking the entity probably because of your call on get, try using find instead of first, because [find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj573936(v=vs.113).aspx)

> The Find method on DbSet uses the primary key value to attempt to find an entity tracked by the context. If the entity is not found in the context then a query will be sent to the database to find the entity there. Null is returned if the entity is not found in the context or in the database.

so you don't have this entity tracked while you are updating it, because you are updating the tracked one itself. 
so in your GetProject, replace this

```
model.Projects.Where(x => x.Id == id).First()
```

with this

```
model.Projects.Find(id)
```

Comment: I now get this error: SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Projects' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. How do I set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON in this kind of project?

Comment: are you changing the id ? 
you shouldn't be changing the id

Comment: That's part of it- the tutorial calls for me to add the line: return id.HasValue ? model.Projects.Find(id) : new Project() { Id = 0 }, implying that I'm setting the identity to 0 when it is creating a new project. You can see how it is used in the view above. I'll try removing that.

Comment: Once I remove it, it has a problem with duplicate keys in the "Technologies" database. I'll put it back in.

Comment: dont assign 0 value to the id, just initiate the object, 0 is value and you can't assign that to your id because it will insert an object with id 0, just do this new Project();

Comment: SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Technolo__3214EC07356D5BA0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Technology'. The duplicate key value is (0).
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: That's what I have now ^^

Comment: I gave the technology database's Id column Identity Specification, and now I get an error telling me I have that IDENTITY_INSERT problem again, but with the "technologies" database instead of the "Projects" one.

Comment: Per what [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7817855/james) said in an above post, I needed to refresh the edmx file after making changes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: so now everything is working  fine ? 
if yes I am glad I helped.

Comment: Yes, it all is. There were really 3 problems: both the project and technology databases did not have their primary keys set to "is identity: true" and I was trying to set the same identity twice. You pointed out and gave me answers to all of them, so thank you.